# Slim templates optional attriutes

Tags: slim-lang

Got the following case

```
 - if video
    - if controls
      video controls="true" loop="true" muted="true" playsinline="true"  uk-video="autoplay: false"
        source src="#{rails_blob_path(media)}" type="video/mp4"
    - else
      video loop="true" muted="true" playsinline="true"  uk-video="autoplay: false"
        source src="#{rails_blob_path(media)}" type="video/mp4"
```

2 questions,

1. how to avoid ="true" for the video attriutes, the browser dont need them, just the slim engaine
2. Is it possible to inline the if inside the video tag and avoid the code duplication elegantly?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this example answers both of your questions:

```
- video = true
- controls = true

- if video
  video controls=controls loop=true muted=true playsinline=true uk-video="autoplay: false"
    source src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4" type="video/mp4"
```

1. You can provide boolean values instead of strings. So for example `loop="true"` becomes `loop=true`. There are [multiple ways](https://github.com/slim-template/slim/issues/433) to achieve similar result with Slim, but to the best of my knowledge, you cannot get pure standalone attributes with Slim's standard config and instead, it will render attributes with empty strings as values. So you have `<element attribute="true">`, want `<element attribute>` but will get `<element attribute="">`.
2. If you switch to booleans instead of strings, you can "avoid the code duplication elegantly", for free. Just set `controls` value to true or false (judging from your code example, it looks like you have already done that)

Comment: You mean `controls=false`? Can you edit your question and share how you assign values to `video` and `controls` variables?